# JavaScript memory leak explanation

Tags: javascript, browser

```
function addHandler() {  
    var el = document.getElementById('el');  
    el.onclick = function() {  
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';  
    }  
}
```

The code above was included in a [Mozilla blog post on JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Memory_leaks) and states that the above code causes a memory leak.

Could someone explain it more than:

> Because the reference to el is inadvertently caught in the closure created for the anonymous inner function. This creates a circular reference between a JavaScript object (the function) and a native object (el).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

with my interpretation, this isn't a memoryleak per-se (sometimes you can't solve your problem without a construct like this, but they are far more complicated), but its not good, because your creating the onclick function everytime new, which keeps a 'link' to its parent (what a closure does). This code would be far better;

```
function clickHandler(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
function addHandler() {  
    var el = document.getElementById('el');  
    el.onclick = clickHandler           
}
```

this way, no closure is created, no unused references are made and no function will be generated multiple times.

Comment: The answer, is then all closures when they are created keep a link to their parent. Hence the `onclick` closure references `el` which in turn references `el`?

Comment: in your questions code, the onclick function has a link to its parent and therefor has access to the ´el´ variable. Inside the function, the ´el´ variable is equivalent to the ´this´, hence you've got a little circle.

Answer (score 1):

@thg435: It looks like that might be a result of using eval.

Executing the following in Firefox or Chrome with a watch on `foo` while breaking at `debugger` reports foo's value as undefined.

```
(function () {
  var foo = "bar";
  return function() {
    debugger;
  };
})()();
```

While executing the following reports foo's value as `"bar"` while breaking at `debugger`:

```
(function () {
  var foo = "bar";
  return function(_var) {
    debugger;
    return eval(_var);
  };
})()('foo');
```

It would be great to get a definitive answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: does a closure capture all variables in the current scope or only those explicitly mentioned? Consider:

```
function makeClosure() {
   var foo = 1;
   var bar = ...some heavy object...

   return function() {
       do_something_with(foo)
   }
}
```

The inner function captures `foo`, does it capture `bar` as well? I guess, yes, because the following prints the correct value:

```
function makeClosure(bar) {
   var foo = 1;

   return function(name) {
       console.log(foo);
       console.log(eval(name));

   }
}

makeClosure('print_me')('bar')
```

So, in your example, `el` gets "inadvertently" caught in the closure (onclick handler). Thus, the closure refers to `el`, and `el.onclick` refers to the closure, qed.