# Which closure variables does javascript allocate?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, closures, lexical-closures

i had yet another dive into javascript memory leaks. my question arose while reading [Ilya Kantor](http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks#memory-leak-size)'s article.

i am aware of ie's memory-leak caused by circular references between DOM-/COM-objects and javascript objects as Ilya points out.

i am also aware of memory-leaks caused by inner functions' lexical environment being implemented as a singleton explained by [david glasser](http://point.davidglasser.net/2013/06/27/surprising-javascript-memory-leak.html).

my case is different: which javascript engines, if any, would leak `data` i.e. allocate `data` to `wrapped`'s lexical environment although there's no reference in the following example?

```
function factory () {
  var data = 'bytebytebyte';
  function wrapped () {
    // (1), pass
  }
  // (2), clean up?
  return wrapped;
}
```

1. `wrapped` has no reference to `data`
2. would you have to set `data=null` anyway to not leak it?

Ilya says (if `data` was set to `null`)

> Now the data still remains in memory as the property of LexicalEnvironment, but it doesn’t occupy so much space.

David says

> Fortunately, JavaScript implementations (or at least current Chrome) are smart enough to notice that `data` isn’t used in `wrapped` [...]

Scott Christopher raised a similar if not the same question in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9209812/1675431).

this is too vague, a definite answer would be great! maybe someone even happened to draw a mem-usage graph on an ie-vm while `setInterval`-ing the `factory` method above?